# InnoDB and MyISAM tables in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, innodb, myisam

I've just start doing some applications with CakePHP, and I have a question about something that is present in the Cookbook:

when saving related model data, Cookbook says: "For transactions to work correctly in MySQL your tables must use InnoDB engine. Remember that MyISAM tables do not support transactions."

Well, I tried this and data was saved correctly with InnoDB, but I was unable to login. So I'd tried with the same tables by using MyISAM, and info was saved correctly too, but now I can login without any problem.

I can't understand why Cookbook recommends to avoid something that works fine. Someone can help me with this? Because I'm going to do my application with MyISAM tables, and I don't want to find any problems later.

Thank you!

Comment: "I can't understand why Cookbook recommends to avoid something that works fine" - It explained it pretty well. Innodb supports transactions.. MyIsam doesn't. Neither is more correct than the other. Why your functionality works or doesn't work has little or nothing to do with the table engine.

Comment: Agree with Mike B, your logins are failing due to something other than your switching to InnoDB.  Also without transactions, you may have problems using built in CakePHP functions like $model->saveAssociated(), which will no longer be atomic.

Comment: you tried a success case and of course it will work fine. Fact is that when the failure in one query occurs, transactions will not work, and you will end up with corrupt data..

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I don't understand why the same login code works well with MyISAM, and fails with InnoDB.